# MVVM How bind MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm, binding

Im trying to add new child(circle) to my Canvas after user click on it. And i want to change position of circles while draging them. 
I want to do it with MVVM but dont know how catch these events in ViewModel.
I need a MouseLeftButtonUp/Down

I've tried wih System.Windows.Interactivity but it didnt helped.
My only idea is to add invisible button and do easy binding `Command="{Binding Method}"`, but it still wont solve my problem, and certainly its not a best option

This in my XAML code (part of it)

`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

```
        <Canvas x:Name="DrawableCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding ElementName=GridContainer, Path=ActualHeight}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=GridContainer, Path=ActualWidth}" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasActionCommand}" x:Name="interactifityFix2">
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this namespace in your XAML:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

then you can add an interaction trigger wich will merge the event with an icommand in your viemodel like so:

```
 <Ellipse>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: I added a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity and then added your code (for ellipse and canvas). But Clicking still dont work. `public ICommand CanvasActionCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(o => CanvasAction()); } }` My method CanvasAction its not executing

Comment: yes but you need to have set the DataContext in advance to this to allow Binding in gerneral
something like this.datacontext = viewmodel or so

Comment: you have to set you datacontext in your code behind to be the class you are derclaring the icommand in
Also my code doesnt set any properties for the elipse so its size will be 0 and you wont be able to click it did you modify that?

Comment: I dont use code behind, but i have datacontext in my XAML

Comment: that should work as well! are you sure your wrote the command exactly the same in your view and your viewmodel?

Comment: can you actually show your xaml maybe we can figure out your issue then

Comment: OK, I dont know when, but it started to work, maybe while i restarted visual. Thanks a lot for help :)